# Javascript - toggled content function only works once

Tags: javascript, css

Not really at ease when it comes to coding, I would appreciate your help on an issue I am facing:

On a landing page, some content should be visible on click or by clicking on a table of content on the top of the page.

On-click toggle works. However, clicking on a menu item, works only once. Then, if I go back to the menu and click on another item of the menu, nothing happens

My guess is that the problem comes from scripts which are "separated" while they should be merged together.

Here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a img
    {
    border: 0;
    }
</style>
<style>
    .ToggleTarget {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function toggle(id) {
                var el = document.getElementById(id);
                if (el.style.display == "block") {
                    el.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    el.style.display = "block";
                    el.style.background= "white";
                }
            }
        </script>

<script type=text/javascript>
if ( location.hash.length > 1 )
{
    toggle(location.hash.substring(1));
}
</script>


Content

<strong><a style="COLOR: #4b4b4b; TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="#1">Title1</a>
<br>
<strong><a style="COLOR: #4b4b4b; TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="#2">Title2</a>

Content


<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%" style="PADDING-TOP: 3px; PADDING-Bottom: 3px" bgcolor="#005a84" valign="top" colspan="4" align="left"><a style="COLOR: rgb(75,75,75); FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="javascript:toggle('1');">
                        <p style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height:10px; line-height:18px;"><strong>HEADER1
                        </strong></p>
                        </a>
                        <div id="1" class="ToggleTarget" style="padding-left:10px"><br>
CONTENT1
                        </div>
</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%" style="PADDING-TOP: 3px; PADDING-Bottom: 3px" bgcolor="#005a84" valign="top" colspan="4" align="left"><a style="COLOR: rgb(75,75,75); FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="javascript:toggle('2');">
                        <p style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height:10px; line-height:18px;"><strong>HEADER2
                        </strong></p>
                        </a>
                        <div id="2" class="ToggleTarget" style="padding-left:10px"><br>
CONTENT2
                        </div>
</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another function to handle the links : (juste behind the toggle function would work)

```
function goToContent(id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if(el.style.display != "block"){
        toggle(id);
    }
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Then reference it in the html

```
<strong><a style="COLOR: #4b4b4b; TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="javascript:goToContent('1');">Title1</a>
<br>
<br>
<strong><a style="COLOR: #4b4b4b; TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="javascript:goToContent('2');">Title2</a>
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qZLsB/13/

Although it should be working, a "cleaner" way to handle clicks would be to use JavaScript DOM events. If you feel like learning about it, you can read more on http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

Comment: Thanks. I've just updated the code above. I made the typo creating the post. It's right in the original code. Still have a problem though

Comment: weird, it's working for me on http://jsfiddle.net/qZLsB/ or I did not understand your problem

Comment: Not that clear indeed.

Probs are the anchored links pointing to the toggled content.

If you have a look at the JS link below, the issue is on "title 1" and "title 2". They are not working properly.
At best, when I click on title 1, it goes to the toggled content1. But then, if I click on Title 2, nothing happens.

http://jsfiddle.net/qZLsB/6/

Comment: They actually work for me. You have to shrink the 'result' frame a little bit in order to see the effect of clicking the anchor link. Also, the contents have to be displayed when you click in order for the anchor links to work.

Comment: But so there is no way to get the anchor links to work with the content hidden?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much Paul! Very helpful and efficient. I would love to +1 your answer but I have not a reputation high enough ..

Answer (score 1):

How about changing

```
href="javascript:toggle('2”);
```

to

```
href="javascript:toggle('2');
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Oops, mistake when I made the sof post. Sorry. The original code was right with '2'

Comment: Then you might give additional details about your problem. I did not understand it exactly. In your sample, what is the table of content, what is the menu item? In your sample there are two anchors, both work perfectly when the above typo has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example of what you were trying to do. I think you just overcomplicated it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/j9HXk/

```
<p onclick="toggleContent('1')"><strong>HEADER1</strong></p>
```

You can use the

click event to do what you were doing. Then you can put some code in the onLoad event to check the hash at the end of the current URL and show/hide the appropriate section.

Let me know if you have any questions about how this is working.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was not clear enough on the first post. The issue is on the anchor links not working properly. That's what I am trying to solve. http://jsfiddle.net/qZLsB/6/